# Como puedo cargar la lista de autores de un libro, en una ventana modal, esto en php usando laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, crud

Tengo mi tabla Autores .. libro .. y una tabla que una las dos ..AutorLibro .. donde se almacena la lista de autores que tiene el libro .... Presento mi lista de libros sin problemas ..pero quiero que al momento de seleccionar el icono de autores .. me despliegue  la lista de los autores de ese libro .. Estoy desarrollando en Laravel .. en esta cuarentena me propuse aprender este lenguaje .. y sería de gran ayuda que me puedan dar una mano
[image: mantenimiento]

Comment: Sin el fragmento de codigo que presenta el problema no es posible responder

Comment: Comentarios: Bienvenido, checa [ask], edita y agrega que llevas hecho y donde ocupas ayuda pues al momento tu pregunta es muy amplia y podría terminar cerrada, por último *Laravel no es un lenguaje sino un framework escrito en PHP*

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor haz el [tour]. Como te indicó @BetaM **laravel** es un **marco de trabajo** que te sirve para desarrollar aplicativos web en **Php** y fue escrito usando **Php**. Te recomiendo que trates de aprender este lenguaje, porque de no hacerlo vas a tener toda clase de problemas para comprender qué ocurre con el código que escribes. Laravel ayuda muchísimo a alguien que sabe php pero puede llegar a ser un verdadero karma para alguien que lo ignora.